# Доступ к файлам nginx

Tags: nginx

есть сервер с обуч. платформой и нужно хранить на нем мультимедиа файлы.
работает под nginx.

как я понял, в конфиге nginx нужно создать

```
location /multimedia/videos {    
   root /var/www/multimedia/videos;    
}
```

сделал данную операцию, перезагрузил nginx, но при обращении https://domain.com/multimedia/videos получаю 404

папка создана от root`a права доступа 755

подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вероятно, в данном каталоге нет индексного файла. по умолчанию — `index.html`

Comment: Если  в эту директорию файл положить и к нему обратиться, какой буде результат?

Comment: Написать правильны root

Answer (score 2):

```
location /multimedia/videos/ {
   root /var/www;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
location /multimedia/videos/ {
    autoindex on;
}

#nginx -s reload
```